# ElasticSearch indexing documents using Java Executors service

Tags: java, elasticsearch, executorservice, elastic-stack

Am trying to indexing more than `100k` documents using Java Executors sevice inorder to index much faster.

Am reading `100k` plus file path from the index `documents_qa` using scroll API. Actual files will be available in my local `d:\drive`. By using the file path am reading the actual file and converting into base64 and am reindex with the base64 content in another index `document_attachment_qa`.

Please find my code below

```
public class DocumentIndex {

    private final static String INDEX = "documents_qa";
    private final static String TYPE = "doc";

     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
            List<String> filePathList = new ArrayList<String>();

            Document doc=new Document();

            logger.info("Started Indexing the Document.....");

            //Fetching Id, FilePath & FileName from Document Index. 
            SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(INDEX); 
            searchRequest.types(TYPE);
            final Scroll scroll = new Scroll(TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(60L)); //part of Scroll API

            searchRequest.scroll(scroll); //part of Scroll API
            SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
            QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery();

            searchSourceBuilder.query(qb);
            searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);

            SearchResponse searchResponse = SearchEngineClient.getInstance3().search(searchRequest);
            String scrollId = searchResponse.getScrollId(); //part of Scroll API
            SearchHit[] searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
            long totalHits=searchResponse.getHits().totalHits;

            //part of Scroll API -- Starts
            while (searchHits != null && searchHits.length > 0) { 
                SearchScrollRequest scrollRequest = new SearchScrollRequest(scrollId); 
                scrollRequest.scroll(scroll);
                searchResponse = SearchEngineClient.getInstance3().searchScroll(scrollRequest);
                scrollId = searchResponse.getScrollId();
                searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();

                Map<String, Object> jsonMap ;
                for (SearchHit hit : searchHits) {
                    Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap = hit.getSourceAsMap();
                    if(sourceAsMap != null) {  
                        doc.setId((int) sourceAsMap.get("id"));
                        doc.setApp_language(String.valueOf(sourceAsMap.get("app_language")));
                        doc.setFilename(String.valueOf(sourceAsMap.get("filename")));
                        doc.setPath(String.valueOf(sourceAsMap.get("path")));
                    }
                    if(doc.getPath()!= null && doc.getFilename() != null) {
                    filePathList.add(doc.getPath().concat(doc.getFilename()));
                    }

                }

                    for (int i = 0; i < filePathList.size(); i++) {
                        Runnable worker = new WorkerThread(doc);
                        executor.execute(worker);
                      }

                        }
            executor.shutdown();
            while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
            }
            System.out.println("Finished all threads");
            }

}
```

Please find the worker Thread :

```
public class WorkerThread implements Runnable {

     private String command;
     private Document doc;
     private final static String ATTACHMENT = "document_attachment_qa";
     private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[0].getClassName());
     Map<String, Object> jsonMap ;
     List<String> filePathList = new ArrayList<String>();

        public WorkerThread(Document doc){
            this.doc=doc;
        }


        @Override
        public void run() {

                File all_files_path = new File("d:\\All_Files_Path.txt");
                File available_files = new File("d:\\Available_Files.txt");

                int totalFilePath=1;
                int totalAvailableFile=1;
                String encodedfile = null;
                File file=null;

                if(doc.getPath()!= null && doc.getFilename() != null) {
                    filePathList.add(doc.getPath().concat(doc.getFilename()));
                    }

                    PrintWriter out=null;
                    try{
                        out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(all_files_path, true));
                        for(int i=0;i<filePathList.size();i++) {
                        out.println("FilePath Count ---"+totalFilePath+":::::::ID---> "+doc.getId()+"File Path --->"+filePathList.get(i));
                        }
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally {
                        out.close();
                    }

                    for(int i=0;i<filePathList.size();i++) {
                        file = new File(filePathList.get(i));
                        if(file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()) {

                                try {
                                      try(PrintWriter out1 = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(available_files, true))  ){
                                            out1.println("Available File Count --->"+totalAvailableFile+":::::::ID---> "+doc.getId()+"File Path --->"+filePathList.get(i));
                                            totalAvailableFile++;
                                        }
                                    FileInputStream fileInputStreamReader = new FileInputStream(file);
                                    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
                                    fileInputStreamReader.read(bytes);
                                    encodedfile = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes));
                                    fileInputStreamReader.close();
                                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                jsonMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                                jsonMap.put("id", doc.getId());
                                jsonMap.put("app_language", doc.getApp_language());
                                jsonMap.put("fileContent", encodedfile);
                                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" End.");

                                String id=Long.toString(doc.getId());

                                IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest(ATTACHMENT, "doc", id )
                                        .source(jsonMap)
                                        .setPipeline(ATTACHMENT);

                                try {
                                    IndexResponse response = SearchEngineClient.getInstance3().index(request); 

                                } catch(ElasticsearchException e) {
                                    if (e.status() == RestStatus.CONFLICT) {
                                    }
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                        }

                    processCommand();

           }
        }

        private void processCommand() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return this.command;
        }

}
```

Issue is, after indexing first document - Its taking very long time to process another document and finally code getting terminated without indexing further.

Comment: What would dramatically improve the performance would be to send batches of documents to ElasticSearch rather than sending one document at a time. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/_batch_processing.html

Comment: @JBNizet - Do we have any examples for bulk index using java api.?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-bulk.html

Comment: @JBNizet - Am using `restHighLevelClient` . how can i prepare `client.prepareBulk`. Am do like below `IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest(ATTACHMENT, "doc", id )
                  .source(jsonMap)
                  .setPipeline(ATTACHMENT);`

Comment: I have no idea. I'm a newbie with Elastisearch. Dig into the documentation.